# Displaying Facebook like box inline with paragraph text

Tags: css, facebook-likebox

I would like to display a like box with count so that it displays as **My text here** [Like] <[2000]

By default, the like box is on a new line so it appears as

```
My text here
[Like] <[2000]
```

At the moment, I'm using CSS to relatively position the div with the following code:

```
<p><strong>My text here</strong></p>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"
style="position:relative; top:-36px; left:230px;"></div>
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used to this code and define parent div width or height according your layout

```
    <p><strong>My text here</strong></p>
    <div style="display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
position:relative;
width:200px;
height:100px;
">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"
    style="position:absolute;
 top:0; 
left:0;">
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This still appears on two lines - I am trying to get it to appear on one line.

Comment: You can see the positioning of your result and my result at http://jsfiddle.net/ktzxN/

Comment: @sinisterfrog now check to this Live demo i think you should want this http://jsfiddle.net/ktzxN/1/

Comment: That is close - thank you.  But it doesn't work for multiline text.  See http://jsfiddle.net/ktzxN/2/

Answer (score 0):

your given link is working fine you just need to add following css property on you `<P>` tag and you need to add css `clear` property also like:

```
<p style="float: left;margin-right: 10px;"><strong>My text here</strong></p>
```

please check for reference

http://jsfiddle.net/ktzxN/3/

Hope it works!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the Solution for Multiline text on the following link!

http://jsfiddle.net/ktzxN/4/

Now this Layout become Liquid you use this layout on any resolution.!!!!!!

Hv Fun :-)

Comment: That floats alongside the paragraph.  I was hoping to get it to display alongside the last word in a paragraph but under any lines above it. Like my username/date after this comment.